# How is Vibranium able to deflect the concentrated power of an Infinity Stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, infinity-stones, vibranium

In Marvel's *The Avengers* (2012), when Loki is about to kill the old man who stood up to him, Captain America jumps in front and deflects the beam shot from the spear (at about 41:15). We later learn that the spear contains the Mind Stone, which gives it its power. How is Vibranium able to deflect the concentrated power of the Mind Stone?

Comment: Because it's very strong material and the power of the mind stone isn't infinite?

Comment: Because the Mind Stone isn't the most powerful at creating physical effects or defeating a physical defense?  Might have been different if it were the Power Stone...

Comment: Well, in What If...? Vision's laser kills Thanos. And the laser is pretty powerful

Comment: But Thanos isn’t vibranium.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What, exactly, is Vibranium able or not able to absorb?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89319/what-exactly-is-vibranium-able-or-not-able-to-absorb)

Comment: I don't know why this was closed as opion-based. We know a good amount about both vibranium and the infinity stones, making an answer being out there likely. Even if there isn't an answer currently, that's not the same as the question being subjective.

Comment: @RogueJedi fully agree

Comment: Thank you... I didn't see the question was closed and still don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this is never addressed in canon, and there are many possibilities:

- It is possible that the Mind Stone has to be directed, and Loki told the stone to use enough power to kill a regular man, not destroy a vibranium shield.
- Loki could have been using his own power, not even calling upon the stone - why use a mighty weapon to kill an insignificant ant?
- Loki may not have actually been going to kill the man, simply knock him down; after all, the reflected bolt did not really hurt Loki much.

Comment: Loki is an alien.